# Rendering an element in a different zoom level or screen size

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm creating a (react) component library for documentation and testing purposes for our company. A kind of style guide. Some of our components have styles that depend on media queries to scale up and down nicely.

Our style guide site is responsive but I would like to be able to render different screen sizes. As an example, I wanted to show how the site header looks like in desktop **and** mobile **without having to resize the window**, as if they were multiple iframes with different zoom levels.

So I was thinking if it was somehow possible to make html elements think they are being rendered in a larger or smaller screen by changing their zoom level. A sort of scaling, while staying within the same limits.

Comment: So I take it actually using iframes is not an option? And you don't want to adjust what you normal header code would be for the example? I can think how you can mimic the mobile behavior by, e.g., wrapping the header in a div and saying `.wrapper header { someStyle: property }`, where the wrapper is mobile width and the styles for `.wrapper header` are equal to the media query styles for the header on mobile. But not sure how you'd do exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I guess I *could* setup react routes to a page that renders the header and then it the style guide page I would render an iframe that links to that route... but that seems so hacky. I was hoping I was missing something obvious.

Answer (score 0):

In google chrome there is a tool who do this.

```
Right Click > Inspect the element > The mobile icon at the top corner right
```

Check my screenshot below.

[image: Tool for responsive]

Cheers mate ;)

Comment: No, I specifically meant zooming a single element. That is not what it does. That's the same as resizing the window.